# cURL PUT/PATCH request with Discord API resulting in error 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, discord

I am using php, oAuth2 (from Discord) and cURL to connect to the Discord API, where after the user authorizes the connection, he will automatically enter the server (guild) with a specific nickname and role, but if the user is already on the server, just changes the nickname and adds the role automatically.

I've had success with Auth2, so I'm looking at it. He returns everything I wanted, using `identy`, `guilds.join` and `email` scopes. However, in the process of adding the member to the server or editing the member, it returns error 400 (BAD REQUEST). And I really don't have a clue what it is, so what I'm seeing seems to be all right.

The strange thing is that yesterday, it was working only in the anonymous browser tab, but today, it even worked in my normal browser, but for other users, it does not work.

To tell you the truth, I've already got error 400 and 403, it's really very confusing.

**My complete code:**

```
class Discord extends CodonModule {
    private static $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
    private static $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
    private static $BOT_TOKEN = 'CLIENT_TOKEN';

    private static $guildID = 453922275248265175;
    private static $roleID = 45129328442467690261;

    public static $authorizeURL = 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize';
    public static $tokenURL = 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token';
    public static $apiURLBase = 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me';
    
    public function login() {
        $params = array(
            'client_id' => Discord::$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri' => 'LINK/request',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => 'identify guilds.join email'
        );

        // Redirect the user to Discord's authorization page
        header('Location: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize' . '?' . http_build_query($params));
        die();
    }

    public function request() {
        if($this->get('code')) {
            // Exchange the auth code for a token
            $token = $this->apiRequest(Discord::$tokenURL, array(
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                'client_id' => Discord::$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret' => Discord::$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
                'redirect_uri' => 'LINK/request',
                'code' => $this->get('code')
            ));
            $logout_token = $token->access_token;
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token;

            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }

        if($this->session('access_token')) {
            $user = $this->apiRequest(Discord::$apiURLBase);
            $userID = intval($user->id);
            $userTAG = $user->username.'#'.$user->discriminator;

            $newName = 'Teste';
            
            $params = '{"access_token": "'.$_SESSION['access_token'].'", "nick": "'.$newName.'", "roles": ['.Discord::$roleID.']}';
            $code = $this->membersRequest($userID, 'PUT', $params);

            // The pilot is not on the guild
            if($code == 201) {
                $this->show('discord/discord_success.php');
                return true;
            } elseif($code == 204) {
                // The pilot is already on the server
                $params2 = '{"nick": "'.$newName.'", "roles": ['.Discord::$roleID.']}';
                $http = $this->membersRequest($userID, 'PATCH', $params2);

                if($http == 204) {
                    $this->show('discord/discord_success.php');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->show('discord/discord_error.php');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $this->show('discord/discord_error.php');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    function apiRequest($url, $post=FALSE, $headers=array()) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if($post)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';

        if($this->session('access_token'))
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->session('access_token');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return json_decode($response);
    }

    function membersRequest($userID, $post, $params) {
        $membersURL = 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/'.Discord::$guildID.'/members/';
        $url = $membersURL.$userID;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bot ' . Discord::$BOT_TOKEN,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
        
        curl_exec($ch);
        $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        
        return $http;
    }

    function get($key, $default=NULL) {
        return array_key_exists($key, $_GET) ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
    }

    function session($key, $default=NULL) {
        return array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION[$key] : $default;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should look in the response body of the errors you are getting for more information. Might shed some more light.

Comment: Okay, I'll see. Currently my site has down because CloudFlare is probably suffering from DDOS attack, when I'll come back I'll see. Sorry for that.